# How to implement a all inclusive random number function in Clojure?

Tags: java, random, clojure

I was wondering how to have inclusive random numbers in Clojure. I came up with this:

```
(import java.util.Random)

(def rnd 
  (Random.))
(defn random-float 
  [min max rnd] 
  (+ min (* (.nextDouble rnd) (- max min))))
```

It seems that Java only has inclusive/exclusive random functions. According the documentation:

> The general contract of nextDouble is that one double value, chosen
>   (approximately) uniformly from the range 0.0d (inclusive) to 1.0d
>   (exclusive), is pseudorandomly generated and returned.

Is there a way to have an inclusive/inclusive version of this function. I was thinking about increasing the maximum value with a tiny bit (0.0000000000000001). Not sure what is the impact if I do so.

Would this work?

```
(random-float 0.0 1.0000000000000001 rnd)
```

Comment: Here's an interesting write-up on the behavior of Java's `Random.nextDouble`: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue198.html. I think in practice it's extremely unlikely you'll ever get a random `double` value that touches a boundary, so whether the upper bound is exclusive/inclusive might not make a difference for what you're doing.

Comment: Why? ........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important is the double precision for your case?

You could use integers for everything with clojure.core's `rand-int` e.g:

- for a number between 0-100: `(rand-int 101)`
- for a number between 0-1000: `(rand-int 1001)`
- etc

I'd also note that there are other Clojure rand-style functions such as `random-sample` and `rand` ; if `rand-int` isn't what you're looking for, still you probably won't need to fallback to Java.